# authlib: some client_kwargs in config are not used

Tags: authlib

Love authlib overall. Question about **client_kwargs** described in 
https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/frameworks.html 
and https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/django.html

**Problem statement**: I tried to pass "scope" and "audience" key/value pairs in the client_kwargs dict, but only "scope" key/value is used for generating URI for authorization. 
I need to pass "audience" for Atlassian OAuth2.0 https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-authorization-code-grants-3lo-for-apps/

**Workaround found** after some tinkering by passing "audience"="api.atlassian.com" to oauth.atlassian.authorize_redirect.

**Question**: Is **client_kwargs** in oauth.register/AUTHLIB_OAUTH_CLIENTS intended only for certain keyword arguments? If so, would be great to share it in the documentation; otherwise it would be convenient to set it in config together with everything else.

This behavior was found in 0.12.1 and 0.13.dev0.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because OAuth 1.0 and OAuth 2.0 are different, this `client_kwargs` are designed to pass extra parameters to either `OAuth1Client`/`OAuth1Session` or `OAuth2Client`/`OAuth2Session`.

For your case, there is a `authorize_params`. You can put `audience` in your `authorize_params`:

```
oauth.register(
    ....
    authorize_params={'audience': '...'},
    ....
)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Would be great to describe the magic of "authorize_params" in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I'll add it in documentation.